# JavaScript not correctly passing variable?

Tags: javascript

Before I begin, let me state I'm a noob at JavaScript... so I'm sure the following is a dumb question. However, I'm stuck -- any help is appreciated.

I'm using BlockAdBlock script found at https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock. I've setup my HTML file as so:

```
   <script>var blockAdBlock = false</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="blockadblock.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    myBlockAdBlock = new BlockAdBlock({checkOnLoad: true, resetOnEnd: true});
    var abcdefg = 0;
    function adBlockNotDetected() {
            alert('AdBlock is not enabled');
            abcdefg = 1;
        }
        function adBlockDetected() {
            alert('AdBlock is enabled');
            abcdefg = 2;
        }

    if(typeof myBlockAdBlock === 'undefined') {
        adBlockDetected();
    } else {
        myBlockAdBlock.on(true, adBlockDetected).onNotDetected(adBlockNotDetected);
    }
```

The code works fine in regards to BlockAdBlock and is directly off of BlockAdBlock's github page -- the alerts in the adBlockNotDetected and adBlockDetected functions trigger as expected. However, I'm unable to properly set the value of variable abcdefg; I'm expecting abcdefg = 1 or abcdefg = 2 depending on if ad block is detected or not but I always get abcdefg = 0. I'm totally stumped as to what I'm doing wrong.

Help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Your js could be running before the blockadblock.js has time to load and execute. Try wrapping your code in a document.onreadystate handler.

Comment: @TomDDD I don't think that is the issue. I added alert('Ad block is enabled'); to function adBlockDetected() and something similar to  function adBlockNotDetected() -- both alerts trigger just fine as expected, so the issue can't be with blockadblock.js.

Comment: my guess is that you used the  `abcdefg` variable BEFORE the callbacks were executed - the name `on` suggests they are called asynchronously, but you would have to look at the documentation (or implementation) to be sure

Comment: @Aprillion I'm using abcdefg in code after the callsbacks listed above. Is it possible for the code that uses abcdefg to execute before the above-mentioned code? Is it possible for JavaScript code that comes AFTER to execute BEFORE? Sorry, noob question.

Comment: yes, very much so - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: @Aprillion Ah, that makes sense. Yes, you are probably correct then. Okay, based on that, I've modified my code accordingly and it works now. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to make sure a piece of code is executed AFTER some callback is exexuted, you can put the code into a function and call if from the 1st callback function, e.g.:

```
var abcdefg;
function adBlockNotDetected() {
    console.log('AdBlock is not enabled');
    abcdefg = 1;
    executeSomethingElse();
}
function executeSomethingElse() {
    console.log(abcdefg);
}
```